# Is there any way to increase the speed that a webpage is rendered?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am running into a problem where I need to show a table with ~200 rows and each row has a clickable link that triggers some code on it, and those links cannot be clicked for about ~5 seconds as the page renders the table, and they need to be clickable basically immediately.

I initially thought that going through the code in PHP slowly for whatever reason was the cause but if I spit out some timestamps at the top of the page and then the bottom they are the same, despite the fact that I can watch the table being populated/growing in size and the final timestamp only appearing after ~5 seconds has passed.

So as far as I can tell it's the browser itself rendering all these elements that is the cause of the slowdown? If I do an ob_start, output the contents of my table, and then echo out the contents of the buffer I see the same behavior which I think reinforces that.

Am I off the mark here or does that sound right? And if so what can I do about it?

Comment: So many things happen between PHP finishing building a page and the page completely rendering in the browser

Comment: You can use browser inspector, network tab to see where the time is spent.

Comment: Apache has to send it. The internet has to transport it in packets to the user, via multiple routers, the PC has to buffer the packets and possible reorder them correctly, then the browser has to render the HTML recieved. ___To name but a few___

Comment: if there are so many things to click on this table, then the delegation of events should be better used

Comment: there is also the way to code that, if the table arrives as text in html that the browser must interpret, then necessarily it may take time, especially for a long text where it is obliged to reconstruct packets transmitted by IP . would need a minimal ajax info and let the Js fill / display the array with cloning similar items

Comment: @Dharman https://imgur.com/a/1qel7mI this is what the network inspector looks like, it's not doing any ajax work, just running a query and echoing out the results. You can see there's a deadzone from 1s to 6s, though I'm not sure what the significance of that is

Comment: @MrJ I'm not very familiar with event delegation but quickly googled it. I am just echoing out <a onclick='do_thing(ID_NUMBER)'> links from PHP in each row, so would I instead drop the onclick function, attach one to the table and then keep my ID_NUMBER info in a data-IDNUMBER attribute, and look at that for my table click handler?

Comment: if you put JS code inside HTML tag element, this is the worst for loading and execute !

Comment: @MrJ even if it's just adding on click and pointing it to a function?

Comment: well this just a part of your problem, but just think of the interpreting work for a browser when you add js code inside html..

Comment: What have you done to cache the results of this table? Nothing says the data must be fetched on the fly. It could all be pre-rendered and your click events just show or hide data that is already present. Course, without seeing the code it is hard to tell what you're up to here.

Comment: you also can activate GZIP Compression, after séparating HTML from CSS and JS

Comment: @KaiQing It's a score card so at a glance you would need to see the entered scores for each of the players. I do offload what I can do be retrieved when you do click on the players name though.

Comment: @MrJ It seems we're already doing GZIP unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Some tips that can make a positive difference for you:

**1)** Some browsers firstly load the table into memory and only renders it when the closing tag `</table>` is found. While the table is loading, users can't see anything. A possible workaround it may be, instead of having only one big table, many small tables, each one opening and closing fast, with small chunks of data.

As paradoxal as it may seen, this may require a little bit of code, so in practical terms your page gets bigger in kbytes, but it will render and show itself very fast (because every "little" table will open, load and close easily), improving much the user experience - even if it will take a little bit more of seconds to completely load the entire page, comparing with the situation you have now.

So, instead of open one only `<table>` at the beginning, loop inside separating lines by `<tr></tr>` and only at the end put a final `</table>`, close the table after all `</tr>` and open another one. I mean:

Change this:

```
<table>
   <tr><td> ... your contents here ... </td></tr>
   <tr><td> ... your contents here ... </td></tr>
   <tr><td> ... your contents here ... </td></tr>
   <tr><td> ... your contents here ... </td></tr>
   ... etc
</table>
```

To this:

```
<table><tr><td> ... your contents here ... </td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td> ... your contents here ... </td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td> ... your contents here ... </td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td> ... your contents here ... </td></tr></table>
... etc
```

**2)** If you can't implement the first suggestion, above, but can define the width of each column of the table, then a little trick can result in a fast rendering of your table: when the browser is rendering the table and it finds that a cell needs more space, it will re-render the whole table with an increased width for the specific column. If the table contains a lot of data, it might take the browser a lot of time to re-render (every time it need to fix) the table.

To avoid that, set the table’s CSS property `table-layout` to `fixed`. Then the browser will take the first row of the table as the fixed and defined width of all its columns, not needing to re-calculate and re-render every time. So specify the width of columns in the first row.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't do it, I was able to try both and I'm still not able to click on a link until all players are rendered in their various tables. I also implemented MrJ's suggestion below to no effect.

Comment: Thanks for your return. Just for testing purposes, try turning off your link or text css styles. Maybe all this delay for you to be allowed to click on a link is being complicated by your text layout styles. If you do find some positive implications, then you will have to figure out a manner to apply styles without degrading UX.

Comment: During one of my tests I cut out all the table/tbody/etc. elements and just echo'd out everything in unstyled spans and divs, and it was rendered instantly. I think that led me down the wrong path because the real culprit in the end was someone echoing out a console.log inside it's own script element like twenty times per row. Once I removed that it was rendered instantly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice! Glad that it worked after all. Congrats to you to have solved that. Keep coding.

Answer (score 1):

event delegation usage is something like that =>

```
document.querySelector('#TableID').onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('a')) return;
  e.stopPropagation();

  let val_ID_NUMBER = e.target.dataset.id_number;  // lower case only

  if (val_ID_NUMBER)  // if this one exist...
  {
    // do your stuff with ..
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response on this, I just tried that out and wasn't able to see a difference unfortunately. I'll keep it in mind for stuff like this in the future though, if that's how it's meant to be done.

Comment: The culprit in the end was someone echoing out a console.log inside it's own script element like twenty times per row. Once I removed that it was rendered instantly. Thank you for your help.